# Genéricos e Comparable em Java

Tags: java, herança, genéricos

Estou com uma questão que não consigo ver respondida, se alguém me conseguir dar uma explicação plausível ficarei grato.

Assumindo que tenho 2 classes:

```
public class Figura implements Comparable<Figura>
{
    private final int largura, altura;

    Figura(int l, int a)
    {
        largura = l;
        altura = a;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Figura o) 
    {
        if((o.largura*o.altura) > (this.altura * this.largura))
            return 0;
        else
            return 1;
    }


}


public class Rectangulo extends Figura 
{
    Rectangulo(int altura, int largura)
    {
        super(altura, largura);
    }


}
```

Quando tento criar um método genérico que permite comparar 2 elementos, se fizer:

```
 public static <T> int comparaRect(T rect, Comparable<? super T>  outroRect)
 {
     return outroRect.compareTo(rect);
 }
```

Funciona sem problema. 
Mas se fizer:

```
  public static <T> int comparaRect(T rect, Comparable<? super T>  outroRect)
     {
         return rect.compareTo(outroRect);
     }
```

Já não funciona. Ficando com o erro de *cannot find symbol T* etc.

A minha questão aqui é: Porquê que só consigo fazer de uma maneira e não das duas, uma vez que um elemento é herdado do outro e logo também herda a interface comparable Figura?

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Talvez porque não tem como saber o tipo de `rect` nesse momento, somente em tempo de execução, e ja o tipo de `outrorect` sim(um Comparable com supertipo parametrizado).

Comment: Ok, compreendo. Mas na prática, de todo o modo, apesar do compilador não saber na hora de compilar, tanto 1 como outro estão corretos, certo? Curiosamente se eu acrescentar na classe herdada à frente do extends Figura, também um implements Comparable<Figura>, já irá funcionar, mas do ponto de vista sintático não me faz muito sentido uma vez que a classe pai já tem a interface implementada.

Comment: Se o compilador gera erro no segundo, é porque não está correto, não concorda?

Comment: Mas se eu fizer um objeto Rectangulo e outro objeto Figura e tentar fazer rect.compareTo(figura) e figura.compareTo(rect) vai funcionar (já experimentei). Ou seja, só não funciona nos métodos genéricos porque o compilador não consegue garantir que o objeto rect tem o comparable implementado certo? (mesmo que depois venha a ter). ps: editei a minha resposta anterior para acrescentar mais informação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A minha questão aqui é: Porquê que só consigo fazer de uma maneira e não das duas, uma vez que um elemento é herdado do outro e logo também herda a interface comparable Figura?

O problema não tem relação com a herança, o problema está na forma que o método foi montado:

```
public static <T> int comparaRect(T rect, Comparable<? super T>  outroRect) {
   return rect.compareTo(outroRect);
 }
```

Dessa forma, o compilador não consegue garantir(de uma forma segura) que **T** é uma instância que implementa/contém o método **compareTo**, o método aceita qualquer objeto como T rect.

Se você quer efetuar a operação com ambos os argumentos, o método deve ser motando de uma forma diferente:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int comparaRect(T rect, T outroRect) {
   return outroRect.compareTo(rect);
}
```

Ou:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int comparaRect(T rect, T outroRect) {
   return rect.compareTo(outroRect);
}
```

Dessa forma você garante que os dois argumentos **T** implementam a interface **Comparable**.

Comment: Obrigado, era isso que queria esclarecer efetivamente. Tem tudo a ver com o compilador quando processa o type erase, saber o que pode ou não fazer, apesar de sintaticamente estar correto.